# How to write and run objective c programe in windows xp withour using command prompt

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I install `GNUSetup`. Now How i write and rum my obj-c programe without using GNUsetup->Shell command Prompt
And i google for it but i found that weired thing...

> gcc -o hello.exe hello.m -std=c99 -I /GNUstep/System/Library/Headers
>   -L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -fobjc-exceptions

Only for running programe i have to do it again and again. So Please anyone help me out
Is there any IDE exist for obj-c programe run on windows xp

Comment: To run the program just double click on hello.exe. Is that what you are aking?

Answer (score 1):

GNUStep has its own IDE that [you can get here](http://www.gnustep.org/experience/ProjectCenter.html).  I have never tried it, so I can't say if it is any good.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this NetBeans IDE mentions it on this site: [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/community/magazine/html/03/c++/)

Here's another site I had bookmarked that mentions using ProjectCenter:
[Project Center](http://www.jaysonjc.com/programming/objective-c-programming-in-windows-gnustep-projectcenter.html)